# How to detect a push button press and release in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

i have a GUI based in matlab 2015 to code

when i push/ press the button one of edit box data keeps changing but i want its value to keep on changing according to my call back until i release it

for now i have to keep on clicking  my push button again and again which changes my edit box value

Kindly suggest me a workarround

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton27.
function pushbutton27_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton27 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
Freq  = (str2double(get(handles.edit4,'String')))+ 0.001;
if Freq > 20
    set(handles.edit4,'String','20');
else
    set(handles.edit4,'String',num2str(Freq));
end
```

Comment: I tested `buttondown` function but failed.  refer to this [thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/148366)

Comment: I'm working on OS X, in my case, the only way to trigger this function is `right click` that button, that's so wired.

Answer (score 3):

`uicontrol` has only the `Callback` and `ButtonDownFcn` properties that respond to mouse clicks. If the property `Enable` of the uicontrol is set to `'on'`, only the function specified in Callback reacts to left-clicks. If the property is set to `'off'` or `'inactive'` it also reacts to right-clicks. Because for inactive uicontrols you cannot change the Value by clicking on it, I don't see a direct solution using uicontrol.

A solution is to use the figure's `WindowButtonDownFcn` and `WindowButtonUpFcn` properties. For the button down you could use something like:

```
function buttondown(hobj,~,hedit)
hobj.UserData = true;
while hobj.UserData
    pause(0.2); % put a pause so it doesnt change too fast
    hedit.String = datestr(now); % you can set it to anything you want here        
end
end
```

For the button up:

```
function buttonup(hobj,~)
hObj.UserData = false;
end
```

Of course, if you have multiple buttons that have to work this way, in the buttondown function you must test where the cursor's position is that by checking the `CurrentPoint` property.

Comment: from where i can view those WindowButtonDownFcn and up functions can you please elaborate i am a beginner, i reached my call backs by right click but could not find anything like you mentioned

Comment: The `WindowButtonDownFcn` and `WindowButtonUpFcn` are properties of the figure handle object. They must contain either a function handle (a handle to the callback funcion, like `pushbutton27_Callback`  you used in the example) or a cell array in which the first element is a function handle, or a string that is a valid MATLAB expression. More info here: [WindowButtonUpFcn](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html#prop_WindowButtonUpFcn)